# Remove/delete developer identity from Organizer -> Developer profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, xcode4

I have, by accident, exported and imported my colleague's developer identity into Xcode Organizer.
Selecting Developer Profile lists both me and my colleague.
This results in an warning:

Check dependencies

[BWARN]Code Sign warning: code-signing identity 'iPhone Developer' matches multiple identities : 'iPhone Developer: [me]', 'iPhone Developer: [my colleague]' -- 'iPhone Developer: [me]' will be used.

How can I remove or delete his identity from the project/organizer? There is no control+click.

This has also caused that there are two identical provisioning profiles (I suspect the 2nd belongs to my colleague's developer identity). So if I remove the provisioning profile and his certificate, I might get rid of his developer identity.
BUT: I can't figure out which provisioning profile belongs to which developer identity, since I can't see the identity-id anywhere.
Anybody know where to find that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the KEychain Access and delete the multiple identities file.

Comment: What if the unwanted identity is the one of the Team agent? I deleted the Team agents identity from Keychain access, but then I couldn't create any Ad Hoc and Distribution builds anymore. (My account is an Admin account, so I thought I should still be able to do so after deleting the agent's profile.)

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the unwanted identity files from Keychain Access may work in some cases, but if you have "Automatic Device Provisioning" turned on, you may need to add a step. I found that even when I deleted the identity files from Keychain Access, when I restarted XCode, the unwanted certificate would show up back in Keychain Access. To fix this, I had to:

- Open XCode, select "Provisioning Profiles" (under Library in the
  Organizer), and then hit the "Refresh" button at the bottom (assuming
  "Automatic Device Provisioning" is checked).
- At that point I logged in with the developer credentials I wanted to
  use.
- I then closed XCode, deleted the bad profile from Keychain Access,
  and restarted.

This solved the problem for me and my new default profile was the one that I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. open `Get info` window of your project.
2. select `Built` tap.
3. find `Any iOS` and change its value to specific developer profile.

There is some known x-code bug concerning with changing developer profiles.

If above doesn't fix the problem, leave a comment below this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Me again.

If you want to delete a specific developer profile, follow this.

1. Open `Organizer`.
2. Select `Provisioning Profiles` from left bar.
3. Right click on the one of listed profiles and there should be `Delete Profile` drop-down menu.

Comment: That will only delete the provisioning profile, not the developer profile.

Comment: Yeah. I was asking about how to delete the Developer profile. This only deletes the provisioning profile